# Unable to send string to a controller method via ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1. I want to send a "year" value as the input parameter of my method controller. when I debug my project I can see that "year" has a value in ajax call but the argument of year in the controller method is null. I appreciate if anyone can suggest me to solve the issue.
Here is the related code in razor view:

```
  $('#exampleModal').modal('@ViewBag.ModalState');

            $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
             
                var year = $("input[name='Year']:checked").val();
                console.log('myyear:' + year);
  //My problem is here, when sending year value to the 
  //ProductDetails method         
                $.get('@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Home")/' + {year: year}, function (data) {


                $.each(data, function (index, value) {



                    var markup = "<tr><td>" + value.apName +"</td></tr>";

                    $("#classTable").append(markup);
               })
            });
        });
```

Home controller method:

```
public IList<ApiApplicantDTO> ProductDetails(string year)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("year:" + year);
}
```

Comment: Hi is this `'@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Home")/' + {year: year}` right ? Can you try like this `'@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Home")/?year' +year` or simply `'@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Home")/' +year` ?

Comment: Hi @hrz,Did my answer help you resolve your issue?If so could you please accept as answer?if not,please follow up to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure the `year` has value.And your url is incorrect,you need to change like below:

```
var year = "2019";
$.get('@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Home")?year=' + year, function (data) {
    //...
});
```

Result:

[image]